# Unable to record audio of Incoming and Outgoing phone call in Android

Tags: android, android-phone-call

Unable to record audio of Incoming and Outgoing phone call in Android

I am using Broadcastreceiver for detecting Phonecalls, It is working fine.
When ever phonecall is started I am using below code for start recording Phonecall and creating a folder of "CALLLOG", in which each call record will be stored.

```
public void startRecordingStoreFile(){

String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
        File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/CALLLOG");
        if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
            sampleDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String file_name = "Rec_"+out;
        try {
            audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());

 try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();
        recordstarted = true;
}
```

Below code for stopping the record

```
public void stopRecording(){
        if (recordstarted) {
            recorder.stop();
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            recordstarted = false;
        }
    }
```

The extension of audio files are ".amr".

Above code is not recording the audio of a phonecall, it is creating a folder of "CALLLOG" and ".amr" files are stored but audio is not recording.I was working on this from 2 days.

```
For example suppose lets say I am calling to "X" person, 
1.MIC is not recording once the "X"(other) person lift the call, until then audio is recording some times, 
2.Some times MIC instance is not available as mentioned below solution by Afsar,
I have tried with below code but it doesn't work(Sometimes it works, sometimes not).
```

I am unable to record audio of Incoming and outgoing calls.Some times it works, sometimes it is not working.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the past I was trying to record Audio + Video during video call. While device is in call MIC is being used by other processes, so before setting  MediaRecorder AudioSource as MIC just check whether MIC instance is available or not. You can test it like that

```
private boolean validateMicAvailability(){

    Boolean available = true;
    AudioRecord recorder =
            new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 44100,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT, 44100);
    try{
        if(recorder.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED ){
            available = false;

        }

        recorder.startRecording();
        if(recorder.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING){
            recorder.stop();
            available = false;

        }
        recorder.stop();
    } finally{
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }

    return available;
}
```

Simple solution of this problem is to use some CallRecorder Library following is the link.
[aykuttasil/CallRecorder](https://github.com/aykuttasil/CallRecorder) check it.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply Afsar.I will check it and let you know

Comment: Hi Afsar, I have tried with above code but unfortunately it is not working, it is behaving same like before without recording each call log. Can you please help me with this CallRecording ?

Comment: Hi Afsar, I am also trying with library which you mentioned. but I am using Android with Java, when I add above library I am getting "more than one library with package name androidx.vectordrawable" exception.